# How can I append a subscript?

Tags: subscript

In a symbolic computation I might get a symbol `b` to be a subscripted variable with `n` subscripts; for example `b = Subscript[a,1,3,4,6]`. Then I compute another symbol with just one subscript, for example `c = Subscript[a,8]`. How do I write code to "append" `c` to `b` to get `b = Subscript[a,1,3,4,6,8]`? Symbol `b` could have any length.

The numbers are always in increasing order so I don't have to worry about ordering them.

The base of the subscripts is always some `a`.

This is the last step in a code where I have managed a lot of symbolic computations using subscripts and I do not wish to abandon them and have to start over just for this last step. I hope there is a way to do this.

Comment: `AppendTo[b, 8]`?

Comment: Yes, I think it is that simple. I could have sworn that was among the first things I tried. I'll have to work my code again, but I think so. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - `AppendTo[b, c[[-1]]]` is more general

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
appendIndex[b_, c_] := 
  If[b[[1]] == c[[1]], 
   Subscript @@ (AppendTo[List @@ b, Drop[List @@ c, 1]] // Flatten)];
```

Let us check:

```
b = Subscript[a, 1, 3, 4, 6];
c = Subscript[a, 7];
appendIndex[b, c]

Set::write: Tag Apply in Apply[List,Subscript[a, 1,3,4,6],{1}] is Protected.

(* Subscript[a, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]  ')
```

So, it works, even if there is more indices than one:

```
 d = Subscript[a, 7, 8, 9];
    appendIndex[b, d]

    Set::write: Tag Apply in Apply[List,Subscript[a, 1,3,4,6],{1}] is Protected.

    (*  Subscript[a, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]  *)
```

I have no idea though, what do these new messages (that is ...Set:: write....) do here. Would be grateful for an explanations.

Have fun!